# "TimeSpan.Seconds" Value Resets to "1" At 1 Minute 1 Second Using TimeSpan.Pase("h:mm:ss")

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I'm using the following code to test this issue I'm having-

```
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(x);
            y = ts.Seconds;

            Console.WriteLine(y);
```

After 1 minute that code returns the following-

`0:01:01
1`

The value of "x" is a time-stamp formatted like so- "h:mm:ss".

Does anyone know why y == 1 at 1 minutes 1 second, rather than y == 61?

Comment: y is the value of the seconds; ts.seconds explicitly asks for the number of seconds within the minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ts.TotalSeconds` instead of `ts.Seconds`.

`ts.TotalSeconds` returns the number of seconds elapsed throughout the entire time span, while `ts.Seconds` returns just the seconds component.

In your case, you'd expect `ts.Minutes = 1`, `ts.Seconds = 1` and `ts.TotalSeconds = 61.0`.